# NetworkX: length of returns of `G.edges` and `G.nodes` does not match length of edge and node list used to create graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I am learning to use networkx and I am attempting to apply it on large graph. I have a edge list downloaded from https://biomine.ijs.si/downloads/, the data (biomine_3_oct_2018.bmg) is plain text and zipped (biomine_3_oct_2018.zip), it has **1520673** nodes, **32761889** edges. Here is a brief overview of the data head:

```
# _symmetric overlaps
# _symmetric is_related_to
# _symmetric has_synonym
# _symmetric is_homologous_to
# _symmetric functionally_associated_to
# _symmetric interacts_with
BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0000001 BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0048308 is_a 0.414
BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0000001 BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0048311 is_a 0.566
BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0000002 BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0007005 is_a 0.439
BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0000003 BiologicalProcess_GO:GO:0008150 is_a 0.345
...
```

Column meanings are

```
node1  node2  link_type  link_goodness
```

I created a pandas dataframe from this data and I ignored the first 6 lines (start with #). The length of the pandas dataframe is correct (32761889) but when I use networkx to generate a directed graph:

```py
Biomine_data = pd.read_csv('biomine_3_oct_2018.bmg', sep=" ", header=None)
Biomine_data.columns = ["from","to","relation","weightProb"]
G = net.from_pandas_edgelist(Biomine_data, 'from', 'to', ["relation","weightProb"], create_using=net.DiGraph())
```

I got ***32753853***, which is **8036** less than the correct number (**32761889**). Also, the number of nodes is **12086** smaller too, I got ***1508587*** nodes but it should be **1520673**.

```py
len(G.edges)
# return 32753853
len(G.nodes)
# return 1508587
```

I thought about the possibility that the graph might have some symmetric edges (e.g. A->B & B->A), but even so, the number of nodes shouldn’t be less right?

I also tried to create an undirected graph and got different wrong result for number of edges, number of nodes is the same as directed graph, but still wrong:

```py
G_prime = net.from_pandas_edgelist(Biomine_data, 'from', 'to', ["relation","weightProb"], create_using=net.Graph())
len(G_prime.edges)
# return 32744545
len(G_prime.nodes)
# return 1508587
```

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this error? Or is there something about the way networkx works that I am not aware of?

P.S. I read something like `Nodes in nbunch that are not in the graph will be (quietly) ignored. For directed graphs this returns the out-edges.` from https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html, could this be the reason? If so, how do I fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try using `MultiDiGraph` instead of `DiGraph` to create your graph?

Comment: You almost certainly have repeated edges and nodes.  Networkx ignores repeated nodes (because, why do you want the same node to exist more than once?).  For repeated edges - there are cases where repeated edges are meaningful.  For that you should use a `MultiDiGraph` as @warped suggests.

Comment: @warped Thank you, the edges # is correct now!

Comment: @Joel `MultiDiGraph` takes a significantly longer time to complete compared to `DiGraph`, but it worked! The total # of edges is correct now. However, # of nodes is still wrong, so am I to assume that since the number of edges is correct now, the repeated nodes are by default also correct now (despite total # of nodes being wrong)?

Comment: So what I would say is that almost certainly what has happened is that the same node is being added multiple times.  I do not know what is going on with the fact that the original data seems to state there are more nodes.  You should probably try to figure out why the data is giving you repeated nodes.

Comment: So where does the 1520673 come from? Did you get this in the description of the dataset, or did you verify it with the dataframe itself?

Comment: @warped It came from dataset description at https://biomine.ijs.si/downloads/

Comment: You can do a reality check by counting the unique values in the first two columns of your dataframe: `len(pd.concat([df['node1'], df['node2']]).unique())`. If that does not equal the expected number of nodes, in the annotation, the annotation is incorrect.

Comment: @warped Thank you for the fantastic suggestions! The # came back being 1508587, so there is a high chance that the data description provided is actually wrong. I will verify it with the data provider.

Comment: You are welcome. What this tells you in any case is that the graph constructed from the dataframe seems to be ok, and that `from_pandas_edgelist` is doing what it should.